# how to insert big data in mariadb with execution time less than max_statement_time value

Tags: mariadb, insert, bulk-insert

i have some table with this structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `trcdmppdetail` (
  `mpp_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `company_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mppdetail_date` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `position_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `basedon_code_1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `basedon_code_2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mpp_emp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actualemp_onrequest` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mpp_code`,`company_code`,`mppdetail_date`,`basedon_code_1`,`basedon_code_2`,`dept_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 `ENCRYPTED`=YES `ENCRYPTION_KEY_ID`=3488
```

and value on global variable `max_statement_time=60`

i insert 50k row data on thats table but i got error because my query run more than `max_statement_time`
my dba can't allow me to change global variable `max_statement_time=0` becuase he says will be distruption the server.

so how to i insert the data with execution time less than `max_statement_time` value.

Comment: Create stored procedure which inserts your data by 100-1000 rows chunks. For example...

Comment: Can't you `SET SESSION max_statement_time = 999;` before the load?

Comment: this is not allowing from my dba.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the `GLOBAL` setting; change the `SESSION` setting.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to split up your `INSERT` statement into multiple statements.

Assuming you are using `mariadb-dump` or `mysqldump` to create the file with the `INSERT` statement, you can use the `--skip-extended-insert` flag to create a dump file containing one `INSERT` per row in the table. While this will be slower to import than a single statement, it will not run into the problem with the `max_statement_time` variable.

```
  mysqldump --skip-extended-insert yourdatabase trcdmppdetail
```

If the `INSERT` statement is coming from an application, then the only way I can think of is to use an intermediary MariaDB server without the `max_statement_time` limitation. Use `mysqldump` as described above to create a dump file from the intermediary that you can import into the MariaDB server in your question. (It's easy to [install a MariaDB server](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/binary-packages/) - it can for example be installed on a laptop on any major OS, and 50K rows is no problem at all.)

Comment: this is insert from application side (java apps) so i can't using mysldump.

Comment: Hi @febry - I added another paragraph to my answer.